# Strange app behavior on wayland

Tags: gnome, xorg, wayland, gdm, mutter

I am trying wayland for the first few times on ubuntu 23-10, but I am experiencing some problems with apps.
For starters, if I open several windows in chrome, and some of them contain media (video) playing, it can happen that they lag.
Another problem is that several apps, such as obs-studio, change appearance (and cursor appearance) when started on wayland.
Here is the image of obs-studio on wayland: [image: wayland]
and the one on xorg: [image: xorg]

Here in the first line, you can see slider, scale and top bar changed.

If it helps, my laptop has a 3060m video card and I use proprietary Nvidia drivers. Finally, the kernel version I use is 6.5.0, but I have also tried 6.6.0, and it is the same.

Can anyone help me fix it?